# Labeling lines in d3 parallel coordinates

Tags: d3.js

I am currently using this graph as a template for parallel coordinates:
http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281

Under the `economy(mpg)` column, instead of having the ticks labeled with (mpg), i want to label each line with the `name` of the line.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just throwing in another axis and then using `tickFormat(function(d) { return input[d].name ;})` to get the labels.

I also added in `text(function(d) { if (d!= "name") { return d;})` to the previously existing axis